# Is there a limit as to how many times a file can be versioned within Dropbox?

Tags: backup, versioning, dropbox

Further to my question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/52861/how-does-dropbox-version-upload-large-files), I'm just wondering if there is a limit as to how many times a single file can be versioned within Dropbox? For anyone unsure, I'm talking about the number of changes found in this window:
[image]

Any insights?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific limit.

The only limit I see is that the revisions are [kept for 30 days](https://www.dropbox.com/help/113) unless you have the pack-rat subscription.

Comment: I concur I'm not aware of any specific limit. I use it to syncing my Pidgin ~/.purple directory and have 166 revisions of my prefs.xml and my blist.xml has 289 revisions in the past 30 days.